# Instagram API - Fetching list of followers for my account

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am making a widget for my iPhone to fetch data about my Instagram followers. I won't be putting it on the App Store, and I won't be fetching any other users' data.

Can I do this? I have tried to figure out what to do but I think I have to register my website, even though I'm not making a website and this won't be shared with anyone else.

Comment: Yes you have to register a site or an app, because this is the way it's supposed to work. You can probably use a fake website if you don't have one though. Just use one that doesn't exist just to be sure.

Answer (score -3):

As stated in [Instagram Developer Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), you will have to register your application before using the API.

> **1. Register**
>
> We'll assign an OAuth client_id and client_secret for each of your
>   applications.
>
> **2. Authenticate**
>
> Ask users to authenticate and authorize your application with
>   Instagram.
>
> **3. Start making requests!**
>
> Make requests to our API Endpoints with the users' OAuth credentials.

The takeaway here is that you'll need the OAuth credentials to access the API.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But what i'm not sure about is all the information it's asking for? Like website URL, redirect URL, privacy policy, etc. It's just a personal widget.

Comment: I think SO is the wrong place for this question. Instead you should drop their support an email, they are the ones who can help you sort this out